# What parts of a view can't be changed?

Tags: views

Looking at my views listing, I see each has a "Type". The type effects the choices I have when adding fields. I have to create a whole new view if I want something different. Why is this? Many things are editable in the view. What are all the 'base characteristics' about a view that can't be changed?

I'm thinking about 7.x-3, but comparisons welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Type' corresponds to the database table used for queries. This option creates the 'FROM' part of the SQL query. That is really the only part of a view that cannot be easily changed after the initial creation.

[image]

See https://www.drupal.org/node/2287909 for some more information about the basics of Views 3.